# Can Maven model an "Always use the latest" release system?

Tags: maven

I would like to implement a release system similar to the one used at a large PNW company at which I worked recently.  I would like to know if I can model it with Maven (to which I am relatively new).

I have applications A1, A2, ..., An.  They depend on library L.  I would like to designate the next release of L to be version 2.0.  I would like A1 - An to declare dependency on L v2.0.

I would then like to release successive L artifacts, preferably named something like L-[timestamp]-[git-hash] (so that, given an artifact, I can identify the source that created it) as L v2.0.  Any subsequent rebuilds of any of A1 - An would build against that newly-released version.

Can I do this with Maven?

Comment: You can't release an artifact with the same version number multiple times. For each release of L you would have to either increase the version number or at least add a unique suffix. For everything else the answer of ck1 applies.

Comment: @dunni I think you can: You can have multiple artifacts that have exactly the same name, as long as it ends in ...-SNAPSHOT, right?

Comment: Well, a Snapshot is not a release in Maven terms. And if you want to have reproducible release builds for your applications, i wouldn't use snapshots for that (during development it is ok, but not for releases). The maven release plugin would also abort the build, if it detects any snapshot dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to accomplish this with Maven.

Have a look at the Versions Maven plugin.  It has a goal `versions:use-latest-releases` that will replace the release version of an artifact in your POM with the latest released version that it finds in the repository.

For example, you could use the Versions plugin to update the `L` dependency in `A`'s POM before cutting the next release of `A` using `release:perform`.

`versions:use-latest-releases`: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html

`release:perform`: https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks ck1.  Looking into the Versions plugin.  Do you happen to know if it, or an equivalent, can be used from gradle?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike: you should check out ``gradle-versions-plugin`` here: https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: It does work.  The choice of the latest artifact happens from the client side, though.  It doesn't appear that there is any way, on the repository side, to create a name that is dynamically attached to the most recent artifact.